# How to make JsonConverter write key/value rather than key/array

Tags: json, json.net

I have classes that contain identifiers, like this;

```
public class Type1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class Type2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // other properties
}

public class ParentType
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IdConverter))]
    public Type1 Instance1 { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(IdConverter))]
    public Type2 Instance2 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to serialise the `ParentType` to Json, but I don't need to serialise the whole class. I just need the Id because that uniquely identifies the instance. The IdConverter is implemented like this;

```
class IdConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = objectType.GetProperty("Id");
        return (pi != null && pi.PropertyType == typeof(int));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

        if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
        {
            t.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            int id = (int)value.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(value);
            JObject o = JObject.FromObject(new { Id = id });
            o.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but the output Json is not formatted ideally;

```
{
  "Instance1": {
    "Id": 1
  },
  "Instance2": {
    "Id": 2
  }
}
```

I would prefer it to look more like this;

```
{
  "Instance1": 1,
  "Instance2": 2
}
```

Is there some way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I worked it out myself;

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

    if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
    {
        t.WriteTo(writer);
    }
    else
    {
        int id = (int)value.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(value);
        writer.WriteValue(id);
    }
}
```

Result;

```
{
  "Instance1": 1,
  "Instance2": 2
}
```